# Why infinite loop

Tags: c++, stl

I'm making a function that takes a string as input and stores the occurrence of letters from a-z in a map called map1.
I have no idea why the output is going beyond 122 ( int('z') ). I also tried while loop, just in case. Here is the code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void makeAnagram(string a) {
    int map1[122][2];
    for(int i='a';i<='z';i++)
        map1[i][1] = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        map1[a[i]][1]++;
    for(int i='a';i<='z';i++)
    {
        cout<<char(i)<<": "<<map1[i][1]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s ="abcwedddf";
    makeAnagram(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1
d: 3
e: 1
f: 1
g: 0
h: 0
i: 0
j: 0
k: 0
l: 0
m: 0
n: 0
o: 0
p: 0
q: 0
r: 0
s: 0
t: 0
u: 0
v: 0
w: 1
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0
{: 32766
|: 32766
}: 21938
~: 32766
: 0
<and continued>.....
```

Runtime error: `SIGSEGV`

Comment: Why not `std::map<char, int>`? This will come pre-zeroed.

Comment: @john Doesn't work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db9b0a16e56a9f29) (GCC with `-O3`).

Comment: `'z'` has a value of 122.  Your array is valid from 0 to 121.  122 is past the end of the array.  That's probably bad.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yah I know, but it was your comment that solved my problem and I wanted you to get that +15 :(

Comment: Also, if your string contains characters `{|}~` then the counting of those characters will stomp.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume for a moment that you are counting on ASCII encoding.

You are accessing `map1` using out of bounds index when the character is `'~'`. The integer value of `'~'` is 126.  Consequently, your program has undefined behavior.

You can solve the problem by using

```
std::map<char, int> map1;
```

If you want to make sure that it has an item for certain set of characters, you can initialize it accordingly.

```
std::string init_string = "abcdefgh";
for ( char c : init_string )
{
   map1[c] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes your help solves the problem. thaku very much. But still my doubt remains, why does it go to infinite loop

Comment: @RahulChoudhary, it makes no sense to try to find a logical reason for a program's behavior once it runs into undefined behavior. Anything can happen after that.

Comment: I just wanted to understand it so that a similar problem may not occur in the future

Comment: @RahulChoudhary, unfortunately, you can't count on any pattern when it comes to undefined behavior. When your program does weird things, you can, most of the time, assume it's undefined behavior and then try to track down where the problem in your code is.

Answer (score 2):

If `(int)'z'` is `122` (not necessarily the case), then in your loops you are accessing `map1[122][1]`, which is the second element of the 123th element, but the array has only 122x2 elements. Also there are lots of elements in that array you are not using at all. `a` is not `0` and it is not clear what the second dimension is for. Counting frequencies is easiest done with a `std::map` (or `unordered_map` in case you dont care about sorting):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void makeAnagram(string a) {
    std::map<char,unsigned> map1;

    for (auto c : a) map1[c]++;

    for (const auto& e : map1) {
        std::cout << e.first << ": " << e.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes your help solves the problem. thaku very much. But still my doubt remains, why does it go to infinite loop

Comment: @RahulChoudhary oh forgot to mention that. Accessing the array out of bounds is undefined behavior, which means your code could in princple do anything or nothing. You would have to look at the assmbly to understand in details why there is an infinite loop, though it isnt really worth the effort, because with a different compiler or different version of same compiler something completly different could happen

Comment: I changed the array now, it is map1['z'][2] still going to infinite loop.

Comment: @RahulChoudhary I rolled back your edit, because that wasnt the question I and the other answer was answering. Please do not change your question substantially after you got answers. If you have a simillar but different question you can open a new question

Comment: @RahulChoudhary fwiw the problem was still the same. if you decalare an array as `int array[size]` then it has `size` elements and the last valid index into that array is `size-1`

Comment: I just wanted to understand it so that a similar problem may not occur in the future

Comment: @RahulChoudhary dont use c-arrays and a large class of problems is history. In this case you could use a `std::map` to avoid this and similar problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211232/discussion-between-rahul-choudhary-and-idclev-463035818).